# Is there a faster way to arrange numbers according to value?

Tags: java, loops, math

Newbie here. I've figured out how to arrange the numbers from highest to lowest, but it seems to be a really inefficient method, especially with larger groups of numbers. I tried to have five numbers (entered by a user) arranged from highest to lowest, and the whole thing just kinda ballooned from there; below is the incomplete code for that program. It only works if the first number also has the highest value.

Please, tell me there's a faster way to do this.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class Integers
{
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
{


String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the first number.");
String str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the second number.");
String str3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the third number.");
String str4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the fourth number.");
String str5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the fifth number.");
int a = Integer.parseInt(str1);
int b = Integer.parseInt(str2);
int c = Integer.parseInt(str3);
int d = Integer.parseInt(str4);
int e = Integer.parseInt(str5);

// 1 abcde

if ((a>b) && (b>c) && (c>d) && (d>e))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(e);
}

// 2 abced

if ((a>b) && (b>c) && (c>e) && (e>d))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(d);
}

// 3 abdce

if ((a>b) && (b>d) && (d>c) && (c>e))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(e);
}

// 4 abdec

if ((a>b) && (b>d) && (d>e) && (e>c))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(c);
}

// 5 abecd

if ((a>b) && (b>e) && (e>c) && (c>d))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
}

// 6 abecd

if ((a>b) && (b>e) && (e>c) && (c>d))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
}

// 7 acbde

if ((a>c) && (c>b) && (b>d) && (d>e))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(e);
}

// 8 acbed

if ((a>c) && (c>b) && (b>e) && (e>d))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(d);
}

// 9 acdbe

if ((a>c) && (c>d) && (d>b) && (b>e))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(e);
}

// 10 acdeb

if ((a>c) && (c>d) && (d>e) && (e>b))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(b);
}

// 11 acebd

if ((a>c) && (c>e) && (e>b) && (b>d))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(d);
}

// 12 acedb

if ((a>c) && (c>e) && (e>d) && (d>b))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(b);
}

// 13 adbce

if ((a>d) && (d>b) && (b>c) && (c>e))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(e);
}

// 14 adbec

if ((a>d) && (d>b) && (b>e) && (e>c))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(c);
}

// 15 adcbe

if ((a>d) && (d>c) && (c>b) && (b>e))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(e);
}

// 16 adceb

if ((a>d) && (d>c) && (c>e) && (e>b))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(b);
}


// 17 adebc

if ((a>d) && (d>e) && (e>b) && (b>c))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
}

// 18 adecb

if ((a>d) && (d>e) && (e>c) && (c>b))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(b);
}

// 19 adecb

if ((a>d) && (d>e) && (e>c) && (c>b))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(b);
}

// 20 aebdc

if ((a>e) && (e>b) && (b>d) && (d>c))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(c);
}

// 21 aecbd

if ((a>e) && (e>c) && (c>b) && (b>d))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(d);
}

// 22 aecdb

if ((a>e) && (e>c) && (c>d) && (d>b))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(b);
}

// 23 aedbc

if ((a>e) && (e>d) && (d>b) && (b>c))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
}

// 24 aedcb

if ((a>e) && (e>d) && (d>c) && (c>b))
{
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(b);
}


}
}
```

Comment: before print the data, you could sort then first!

Comment: You should read about sorting algorithms, see this for comparison of various algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

Comment: Check out the answers below it should be a good start, but there is definitely a quicker way then what you have done. However I give you credit you did what you could. So just keep practicing, best of luck and welcome to SO.

Comment: Your method isn't all that inefficient in execution, although it's horribly inefficient to code. I wouldn't bother trying to extend it to 6 numbers. For really inefficient algorithms, take a look at [Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) and its variants. To spend your time on something worthwhile, though, follow the suggestion by Manish.

Comment: Wow. That is...quite the piece of code there. Great job breaking down the code like that, but use your spiderman-sense with things like this. Usually I'll start planning something like this, think: "There has GOT to be a better way to do this." Then I google it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array:

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
```

And then iterate through the array and assign values at each index. If you have intentions of sorting the array, invoke `Arrays.sort(numbers);`

Comment: Yes use an array and compare values while you run it trough the loop Google sorting.

Comment: May just fill up the array and then call `Arrays.sort()`?

Comment: OP wants the output to be in descending order.

Comment: May be this will also work (not tested):`Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder())`

Comment: @Manish That would only work if array was `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

use an `Array` or `List` to store `int` values and sort that `Array` or `List`.

If this you use an `Array`

```
int[] arr=new int[5];
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

If this you use a `List`

```
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(list);
```

Then you will have values in ascending order. To get this in descending order you can get values in reverse order.

Comment: OP wants the output to be in descending order.

Comment: @TedHopp Yes, After sorting array or list to ascending order OP can get values in revers order.

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;    
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

... // Class declaration

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the first number.");
    String str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the second number.");
    String str3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the third number.");
    String str4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the fourth number.");
    String str5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the fifth number.");

    Integer[] arr = new Integer[5]; // Use an array
    arr[0] = Integer.parseInt(str1);
    arr[1] = Integer.parseInt(str2);
    arr[2] = Integer.parseInt(str3);
    arr[3] = Integer.parseInt(str4);
    arr[4] = Integer.parseInt(str5);
    Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());

    for (int i : arr)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Note:**
The array `arr` is of type `Integer` (In Java, the `int` type is a primitive , whereas the `Integer` type is an object. You may want to search more about that) to use the `Arrays.sort` methods in descending mode.

Answer (score 0):

This may help :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String NumStr="";
    do{
        NumStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number.");
        try {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(NumStr));
        } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
            NumStr="";
        }
    }while(!"".equals(NumStr));

    Collections.sort(list);

    for (int i : list)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Program terminates when a empty string or a alphabet is typed